# How can automatic processing be estimated in an editing task?

Tags: consciousness, unconscious, automaticity

Is there a way of measuring/estimating the amount of controlled vs. automatic processes that takes place during a text editing task?

I know that asking participants to verbalise their actions and regard non-verbalised processes as automatic is a flawed approach. I came across the process-dissociation procedure, but this seems to refer to automatic/unconscious recollection after a learning task has taken place, and not automatic processes during the task itself.

Any suggestions of references or ideas on how to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean exactly with 'processes'? If you're thinking about actual movements made during editing (i.e. tiping), this [science paper](https://www.sciencemag.org/content/330/6004/683.abstract?related-urls=yes&legid=sci;330/6004/683) might help. Very simply put, they showed skilled typist have two kinds of control processes, one conscious and one unconscious.

(Science 29 October 2010: 
Vol. 330 no. 6004 pp. 683-686 
DOI: 10.1126/science.1190483)

Comment: That sounds like a very useful paper. By 'processes' I mean the mental steps involved in editing, which may comprise actual editing actions as you suggest. I'll look into how they were able to observe unconscious processes in the article - many thanks.